# Is it possible to have a method that I can call one time with (ref int x) and other times with (value int x) --- (ByValue ByRef)

Tags: c#

how can i write a method that at one time can be called by ref for the Argument and other times by Value for the argument?

```
public Form2 f2 = null;
private void BtOpenSecFrm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenNewForm<Form2>(ref f2);
}
```

// the first one opens always only one instanze of the Form

```
public Form3 f3 = null;
private void BtOpenSecFrm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenNewForm<Form3>(f3);// **<-Problem i would like to use the same Methode just without ref**
}
```

//the second creates and shows everytime a new instanze of the form -> multipel froms at the same time

```
public void OpenNewForm<T>(ref T frmNext) where T : Form, new()
{
    if (frmNext == null || frmNext.IsDisposed)
        frmNext = new T();
    if (!frmNext.Visible)
        frmNext.Show();
    if (frmNext.WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized)
        frmNext.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
    frmNext.Focus();
}
```

Comment: That's not possible.  The intention is not that obvious from the snippets, trying to do this with one method is likely to be a mistake.  But consider to make the return type of the method T.  Now you don't need ref anymore, you can assign f2 in the first case and skip assigning f3 in the second case.

Comment: Okay I try to look into that. I don`t understand right away what you mean. Why would a return  solve my poblem. The Form is already show in the Methode befor the return even happens.

Answer (score 3):

You can overload the method so that it can be invoked subject to your actual argument.

```
public void OpenNewForm<T>(ref T frmNext) where T : Form, new()
{
    // your implementation
}

public void OpenNewForm<T>(T frmNext) where T : Form, new()
{
    // your implementation
}
```

Comment: thx for your answere, but that is not what I want to do. I just want to have exactly one methode that does both if possible. Mayby someway with delegates.